# Android Alarmmangaer: Repeat alarm every 5 seconds for the first 60 seconds

Tags: android, android-alarms

Following code will repeat the alarm every 5 seconds. But I want this alarm to get canceled after 60 seconds.

```
 AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 Intent i = new Intent(context, CrawlAlarm.class);
 PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 5, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, CrawlAlarm.class);
final PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 5, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute  

Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        am.cancel(pi);
    }

}, 60 * 1000);
```

This will cancel it after 60 seconds.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much.
You proved that I am an amateur in android development :)